# DefaultSecondUser in Cisco AnyConnect Profile

Tags: cisco-vpn-client

I am editing my Cisco AnyConnect Profile's XML (`C:\Users\Francky\AppData\Local\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client` on Windows 7).

What's the use of the `DefaultSecondUser` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the AnyConnect's preferences file but not the profile itself. When VPN profile has a property to save non-sensitive user preferences, client saves the user inputs (username for example) to this file. This helps client to auto populate user inputs on GUI when establishing VPN connection in the next attempt.

AnyConnect has the capability of two-factor authentication. Secondary authentication can be a certificate or username/password. If username/password is configured on head-end for secondary authentication, client prompts for user to enter the details as shown in the picture.

[image]

"Second Username" input is saved to `DefaultSecondUser` in the preferences file. In the example, client had connection with "foo, bar" and is getting auto populated on the next attempt. Hope this is clear.